# IDA and XRefs in the .data Section

Tags: ida, disassembly

When using IDA, I can press <kbd>x</kbd> on any subroutine to see where it is called from. Eventually I end up in the `.data` section.

But, what am I looking at when I get to this point ?

Are these exports offered by the `.dll` that I'm looking at ? And, if I get to this point, is it safe to assume that there are no other calls to my function (with the exception of dynamically-generated and/or external calls) ? See reference image below for context.

[image: XRefs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more context, but you're probably looking at a [virtual function table (vtable)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). See [Converting a virtual table from .rdata into an IDA struct](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3116/converting-a-virtual-table-from-rdata-into-an-ida-struct) for an example.